# WPF printing FlowDocuments to XPS: printed content not stretching across page. Why?

Tags: wpf, printing, .net-3.5

I'm trying to print a `FlowDocument` with `PrintDialog` to an XPS file. The resulting printed content only appears to stretch across **half** the XPS page, not the entire width of the page. Here is an example of what the resulting XPS document looks like in Windows XPS viewer:

[image: Example of XPS document in Windows XPS viewer]
*(note: it looks exactly the same if I print it with a printer on normal 8x11 printing paper)*

This is the code I'm using to print this document:

```
void Print()
{
    PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
    bool? result = printDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (!result.HasValue)
        return;
    if (!result.Value)
        return;

    double pageWidth = printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth;
    double pageHeight = printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight;
    FlowDocument flowDocument = CreateFlowDocument(pageWidth, pageHeight);

    printDialog.PrintDocument(
        ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)flowDocument).DocumentPaginator,
        "Test print job");
}

FlowDocument CreateFlowDocument(double pageWidth, double pageHeight)
{
    FlowDocument flowDocument = new FlowDocument();
    flowDocument.PageWidth = pageWidth;
    flowDocument.PageHeight = pageHeight;
    flowDocument.PagePadding = new Thickness(30.0, 50.0, 20.0, 30.0);
    flowDocument.IsOptimalParagraphEnabled = true;
    flowDocument.IsHyphenationEnabled = true;
    flowDocument.IsColumnWidthFlexible = true;

    Paragraph header = new Paragraph();
    header.FontSize = 18;
    header.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    header.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    header.Inlines.Add(new Run("Title of my document (will be cut off in XPS)";));
    flowDocument.Blocks.Add(header);

    Paragraph test = new Paragraph();
    test.FontSize = 12;
    test.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    test.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    test.Inlines.Add(new Run("This text should stretch across the entire width of the page. Let's see if it really does, though."));
    flowDocument.Blocks.Add(test);

    return flowDocument;
}
```

`pageWidth` is **816.0** and `pageHeight` is **1056.0**, which should be *more* than big enough to accommodate my text. What could be going wrong?

---

**Edit:** Here are some other things I've tried:

- Tried adding a `StackPanel` with a large width to my `Paragraph` in the `FlowDocument`. Text just gets cut off about halfway across the page.
- Tried assigning `FlowDocument.PageWidth` to a large width. Again, the text just gets cut off about halfway across the page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try setting the `ColumnWidth` property of `FlowDocument` to `pageWidth` - that should fix it.

Comment: I have wasted about 20 pages before your answer. Thank you )